# Как добавить панель над формой редактирования?

Tags: python, django, jinja2

Хочу добавить markdown в админ панель. Из всех markdown`ов заработал tinymce,
но у него отсутствует функция добавления кода.
В итоге сформировалось два вопроса:
1. Можно ли в tinymce добавить свою кнопку и как?
2. Нашел template формы админки, но эта форма зациклена в for. Получается, что панель символов будет появлятся в нескольких местах. Единственное, что приходит в голову, так это добавить html и css через js.

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n admin_urls static admin_modify %}

{% block extrahead %}{{ block.super }}
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% url 'admin:jsi18n' %}"></script>
{{ media }}
{% endblock %}

{% block extrastyle %}{{ block.super }}<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "admin/css/forms.css" %}" />{% endblock %}

{% block coltype %}colM{% endblock %}

{% block bodyclass %}{{ block.super }} app-{{ opts.app_label }} model-{{ opts.model_name }} change-form{% endblock %}

{% if not is_popup %}
{% block breadcrumbs %}
<div class="breadcrumbs">
<a href="{% url 'admin:index' %}">{% trans 'Home' %}</a>
&rsaquo; <a href="{% url 'admin:app_list' app_label=opts.app_label %}">{{ opts.app_config.verbose_name }}</a>
&rsaquo; {% if has_change_permission %}<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}">{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}</a>{% else %}{{ opts.verbose_name_plural|capfirst }}{% endif %}
&rsaquo; {% if add %}{% blocktrans with name=opts.verbose_name %}Add {{ name }}{% endblocktrans %}{% else %}{{ original|truncatewords:"18" }}{% endif %}
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% endif %}

{% block content %}<div id="content-main">
{% block object-tools %}
{% if change %}{% if not is_popup %}
  <ul class="object-tools">
    {% block object-tools-items %}
    <li>
        {% url opts|admin_urlname:'history' original.pk|admin_urlquote as history_url %}
        <a href="{% add_preserved_filters history_url %}" class="historylink">{% trans "History" %}</a>
    </li>
    {% if has_absolute_url %}<li><a href="{{ absolute_url }}" class="viewsitelink">{% trans "View on site" %}</a></li>{% endif %}
    {% endblock %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
<form {% if has_file_field %}enctype="multipart/form-data" {% endif %}action="{{ form_url }}" method="post" id="{{ opts.model_name }}_form" novalidate>{% csrf_token %}{% block form_top %}{% endblock %}
<div>
{% if is_popup %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ is_popup_var }}" value="1" />{% endif %}
{% if to_field %}<input type="hidden" name="{{ to_field_var }}" value="{{ to_field }}" />{% endif %}
{% if save_on_top %}{% block submit_buttons_top %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}{% endif %}
{% if errors %}
    <p class="errornote">
    {% if errors|length == 1 %}{% trans "Please correct the error below." %}{% else %}{% trans "Please correct the errors below." %}{% endif %}
    </p>
    {{ adminform.form.non_field_errors }}
{% endif %}

{% block field_sets %}

{% for fieldset in adminform %}

  {% include "admin/includes/fieldset.html" %}

{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block after_field_sets %}{% endblock %}

{% block inline_field_sets %}
{% for inline_admin_formset in inline_admin_formsets %}
    {% include inline_admin_formset.opts.template %}
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}

{% block after_related_objects %}{% endblock %}

{% block submit_buttons_bottom %}{% submit_row %}{% endblock %}

{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}
    <script type="text/javascript"
            id="django-admin-form-add-constants"
            src="{% static 'admin/js/change_form.js' %}"
            {% if adminform and add %}
                data-model-name="{{ opts.model_name }}"
            {% endif %}>
    </script>
{% endblock %}

{# JavaScript for prepopulated fields #}
{% prepopulated_fields_js %}

</div>
</form></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: покажите настройки tinymce, там должен быть пункт, добавляющий редактор кода и кажется он включен в список по умолчанию

Comment: @СергейЧабаненко, Да, я нашел

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл ответы на свой вопрос  [здесь](https://fosstack.com/how-to-set-up-tinymce-in-django-app)

Устанавливаем tinymce `pip3 install django-tinymce4-lite`
Добавляем в settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
      ...
    'tinymce',
      ...
    ]
```

Добавляем в urls.py tinymce:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    ...
]
```

В settings.py добавлем такой конфиг tinymce:

```
  'height': 360,
    'width': 1120,
    'cleanup_on_startup': True,
    'custom_undo_redo_levels': 20,
    'selector': 'textarea',
    'theme': 'modern',
    'plugins': '''
            textcolor save link image media preview codesample contextmenu
            table code lists fullscreen  insertdatetime  nonbreaking
            contextmenu directionality searchreplace wordcount visualblocks
            visualchars code fullscreen autolink lists  charmap print  hr
            anchor pagebreak
            ''',
    'toolbar1': '''
            fullscreen preview bold italic underline | fontselect,
            fontsizeselect  | forecolor backcolor | alignleft alignright |
            aligncenter alignjustify | indent outdent | bullist numlist table |
            | link image media | codesample |
            ''',
    'toolbar2': '''
            visualblocks visualchars |
            charmap hr pagebreak nonbreaking anchor |  code |
            ''',
    'contextmenu': 'formats | link image',
    'menubar': True,
    'statusbar': True,
```

Можно поиграться с настройками, но мне этого функционала достаточно